# unclarity on IP restrictions

Tags: security

Ok, so in the following article I can read that IP restrictions have no impact on salesforce Mobile. http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005479&language=en_US

The article says the following:

> A note about salesforce.com Mobile: The client application on a
>   customers phone does not communicate directly with the org. It
>   connects with an internally hosted salesforce.com Mobile server which
>   is a part of Salesforce.com service delivery infrastructure and is
>   whitelisted by default. This means there is no impact with Mobile
>   access when IP Restrictions are deployed.

To which applications does this apply now? To all native Salesforce mobile applications?
So applications like Touch, Salesforce Classic, the Chatter app etc etc?

What about third party mobile applications? I assume that those ones will be blocked since they use the API? In the documentation, I read the following:

> When users log in to Salesforce, either via the user interface, the
>   API, or a desktop client such as Connect for Outlook, Salesforce for
>   Outlook, Connect Offline, Connect for Office, Connect for Lotus Notes,
>   or the Data Loader, Salesforce confirms that the login is authorized
>   as follows: ..... here the checks on IP, login hours etc.

Has anyone tested this through who can confirm my assumptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got an answer in the meantime from a contact at Salesforce.
The exception on the impact of the IP range limitation that is mentioned in the documentation only applies to the Salesforce Classic (Salesforce Mobile) application.

For the Salesforce chatter application, there exists a workaround to bypass the IP restriction.

For Salesforce Touch, there is no way to bypass the IP range limitation.